# Filter category taxonomy with tabs

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, routes

i have a node which is of content type "Album", they all have categories defined by terms , and i want the user to be able to choose which category he want to filter by but with tabs instead of a dropdown list.

Cant find anything on the internet so this is my last hope.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [quicktabs](https://drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module. You could use it to embed views in each tab, based on your required filter options there. For example, you can pass a contextual filter option to the quicktab for a single view display to show that content only.

Alternatively, the [better_exposed_filters](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module may provide some options for you, such as a list of links, instead of a select box.

Comment: Method #1: How would you do that? the way i see quicktabs module, i gotta add each term as a tab manually?

Comment: You can pass view contextual filters for the term id to the view in the quicktabs configuration.