# How do i create complicated content type?

Tags: nodes

My apologies for bad english.

I want to create educational website with user generated content. Sort of like wikipedia. The problem is content is a little bit complicated.
It must have 4 tabs, which represent 4 stages of learning. Each individual tab must have guide (a basic content page with a text), a f.a.q. page, and a forum for users to open topics related to subject of learning and current stage.
I draw a markup for better undearstanding:
[image]

I tried to make it myself by creating a content type with a Field Group module and ended up with this:
[image]

Current problems are: a) guide on each tab is just a text but needs to be a title, which leads to page with a guide; b) have comments instead of forum under the tabs and no idea how to make it.

I would absolutely appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection)

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can
>   be attached.
>
> A field collection is internally represented as an entity, which is
>   embedded in the host entity. Thus, if desired field collections may be
>   viewed and edited separately too.

and [Field Collection Tab formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_tabs)

> Field collection tabs provides a field formatter that allows you to
>   output a multi value field collection field as a tabset, with one tab
>   per field collection item.
>
> You can optionally choose a field from the field collection item to be
>   used as the tab title.

modules.

Your common elements, guide, faq, forum goes into the field collection. Also put the stage title as a field in the field collection. Then use the stage title field as the title for the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

- to create link to Guide page you can use [Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/link) module
- consider use of taxonomy terms for stages
- don't apologize for your English ;) It's very good IMO.

More info here: [Filter category taxonomy with tabs](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86400/filter-category-taxonomy-with-tabs)